# NullPointerException with log4j with maven

Tags: java, maven, logging, nullpointerexception, log4j

I have main pom, and two modules (sub poms), first of them contains dependency to log4j.
First module - some utility classes.
Second - tests for first module (jcstress) that compiles to sub-jar using shade plugin.
compilation works fine, but then run tests (second module), it fails with this error.
I have to dependencies for log4j in first module and they are copied to second one:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>           at avalsa.util.ConcurrentSortedLinkedList.(ConcurrentSortedLinkedList.java:12)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>           at org.openjdk.jcstress.util.Reflections.getClasses(Reflections.java:64)
>           at org.openjdk.jcstress.vm.ContendedTestMain.main(ContendedTestMain.java:44)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.getClassLoaders(LoaderUtil.java:115)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.(ProviderUtil.java:66)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.lazyInit(ProviderUtil.java:146)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.hasProviders(ProviderUtil.java:130)
>           at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:89)
>           ... 5 more

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove log4j dependency in your POM and 
Add this dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What problem was with log4j2?

Comment: I found , there is no Problem in log4j 2.x version . the problem is in your dependency you have to add binding library to your POM and also you have configure ```log4j.properties /log4j.xml``` file for ```2.x``` version properly

Comment: What do you mean by "you have to add binding library to your POM" ? I did change only log4j dependency and reconfigure 'log4j.xml'

Comment: https://ibb.co/gAiPNo Visit this ImageURL you have to add these three dependencies and then make a change in log4j.xml.